# Socket read/write file size variation at sender and receiver

Tags: sockets, unix, network-programming, network-protocols

I want to send the data in same size chunks.
but if file size is not multiple of chuck size then there will be addition of extra
size at receiver side.
I thought of solution get the file size and divide the chunk with respect to file size.
however this solution is not working can anyboby tell me

Here is my code

```
total_chunks = size / CHUNK_SIZE;
partial_chunks = size % CHUNK_SIZE;
int write_fd = open("test3.txt",O_CREAT|O_WRONLY,0777);
if(fd != -1)
{
    if(total_chunks >= 1)
    {
        data_chunk = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * CHUNK_SIZE);
        bzero((char *) data_chunk, sizeof(data_chunk));
        for(iteration = 0;iteration <total_chunks;iteration++)
        {
            read(fd,data_chunk,sizeof(data_chunk));
            write(write_fd,data_chunk,CHUNK_SIZE);
        }
        free(data_chunk);
    }
    if(partial_chunks != 0)
    {
        data_chunk = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * partial_chunks);
        bzero((char *) data_chunk, sizeof(data_chunk));
        read(fd,data_chunk,sizeof(data_chunk));
        write(write_fd,data_chunk,sizeof(data_chunk));
    }
    close(fd);
    close(write_fd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(data_chunk) will give you the size of the datatype of data_chunk, it's the same as sizeof(char *). There is no function that will give you the size of a memory block allocated by malloc, just replace it by CHUNK_SIZE instead for full blocks and partial_chunks further below, i.e:

```
total_chunks = size / CHUNK_SIZE;
partial_chunks = size % CHUNK_SIZE;
int write_fd = open("test3.txt",O_CREAT|O_WRONLY,0777);
if(fd != -1)
{
    if(total_chunks >= 1)
    {
        data_chunk = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * CHUNK_SIZE);
        for(iteration = 0;iteration <total_chunks;iteration++)
        {
            read(fd,data_chunk,CHUNK_SIZE);
            write(write_fd,data_chunk,CHUNK_SIZE);
        }
        free(data_chunk);
    }
    if(partial_chunks != 0)
    {
        data_chunk = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * partial_chunks);
        read(fd,data_chunk,partial_chunks);
        write(write_fd,data_chunk,partial_chunks);
    }
    close(fd);
    close(write_fd);
}
```